# Sorting a list of unequal-size vectors in r

Tags: r, sorting

Suppose I have several vectors - maybe they're stored in a list, but if there's a better data structure that's fine too:

```
ll <- list(c(1,3,2),
           c(1,2),
           c(2,1),
           c(1,3,1))
```

And I want to sort them, using the first number, then the second number to resolve ties, then the third number to resolve remaining ties, etc.:

```
c(1,2)
c(1,3,1)
c(1,3,2)
c(2,1)
```

Are there any built in functions that will allow me to do this or do I need to roll my own solution?

(For those who know Python, what I'm after is something that mimics the behavior of sort in Python)

Comment: That's the ["Lexicographical order"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) you're looking for.

Comment: Just to note (I should have specified this in the question):  the elements of each vector may be more than a single digit e.g. one vector could be c(1,10,1)

Comment: In order for your sorting to make sense, all vectors should be of the same length (i.e., be filled with `NA` values). In that case a `matrix` or `data.frame` would be a sensible data structure. My answer assumes that you do not want to change your vectors.

Comment: @Roland: Why would a sorting with variable vector length make no sense? Doesn't the order of words in a encyclopedia follow the same principle?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the idea that sorting only makes sense if all vectors are of the same length.  I'm playing about with a poker program, translating the Python code here: https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs212/unit-1 into R to see how it works out.  The order of hands is worked out using vectors of unequal length in the program at that link (see "Complete Code For Poker Problem"), and I think it is a meaningful use case of sorting unequal length vectors.  Having said that, I agree that to solve this problem in R, it seems to be easiest to make all the vectors the same length

Comment: We are not dealing with lexicographical order here but with numeric sorting. And in that context the concept of ordering vectors of unequal length just seems strange to me. But YMMV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ll <- list(c(1,3,2),
           c(1,2),
           c(2,1),
           c(1,3,1))
```

I'd prefer using `NA` for missing values and using `rbind.data.frame` instead of `paste`:

```
sortfun <- function(l) {
  l1 <- lapply(l, function(x, n) {
    length(x) <- n
    x
  }, n = max(lengths(l)))
  l1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, l1)
  l[do.call(order, l1)] #order's default is na.last = TRUE
}

sortfun(ll)

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 3 1
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1 3 2
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 2 1
```

Comment: Nice. I guess an improvement on this line could be `ll[do.call(order,lapply(seq_len(max(lengths(ll))),function(x) vapply(ll,"[",FUN.VALUE=1,x)))]`, in which there is no need to build a `data.frame` in the process.

Comment: Thanks.  While watching this thread I was attempting to create my own solution.  It was similar to yours, but I really liked your `length(x) <- n` trick, which I hadn't realised was possible.  I also didn't know you could do `rbind.data.frame` (I had this in two steps).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses `data.table`.

The result is a rectangular `data.table` with the rows ordered in the form you described. `NA` values are filled in where the list item was a different length.

```
library(data.table)
setorderv(data.table(do.call(cbind, transpose(l))), paste0("V", 1:max(lengths(l))))[]
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1:  1  2 NA
# 2:  1  3  1
# 3:  1  3  2
# 4:  2  1 NA
```

---

This is ugly, but you can use the result on your list with something like:

```
l[setorderv(
  data.table(
    do.call(cbind, transpose(l)))[
      , ind := seq_along(l)][], 
  paste0("V", seq_len(max(lengths(l)))))$ind]
```